# Determinant of a particular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What is the best way to find determinant of the following matrix?

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&ax&a^2+x^2\\1&ay&a^2+y^2\\ 1&az&a^2+z^2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I thought it looks like a Vandermonde matrix, but not exactly. I can't use  $|A+B|=|A|+|B|$ to form a Vandermonde matrix. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean $\vert A + B \vert = \vert A \vert + \vert B \vert$?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

\begin{align}
&|A|\\
&=\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1&ax&a^2+x^2\\1&ay&a^2+y^2\\ 1&az&a^2+z^2
\end{matrix}\right) \\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
1&ax&a^2\\1&ay&a^2\\ 1&az&a^2
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
1&ax&x^2\\1&ay&y^2\\ 1&az&z^2
\end{vmatrix} \tag{multilinearity on 3rd column} \\
&=0+a\begin{vmatrix}
1&x&x^2\\1&y&y^2\\ 1&z&z^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= a (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)
\end{align}

Comment: i am confused which answer to be accepted ....all are nice....

Comment: @neelkanth I suggest you throw a dice.

Comment: thanks....................................

Comment: I rolled I dice three time for better .... got three different choices every time .

Comment:  Perhaps you can start a new [tag:dice] question for that.

Comment: @neelkanth There are three answers. Give each author $2$ numbers from $1$ to $6$. Now throw the dice at most $4$ times and choose the first person that wins $2$ times. :P That should do it. :P

Comment: @stressedout If possible, throwing multiple dice at a time can save time and effort. :-)

Comment: But that requires more resources. :P So, you save time but you have to have multiple dice then. :P

Comment: @stressedout You're right.  That's why I say if possible.  Perhaps OP was busy with a [tag:simulation] of the Law of Large Number that he couldn't decide which answer to accept. :xd

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Can you look my this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116375/determinant-of-a-3-times-3-matrix thanks.

Comment: Seen.  Sorry, I'll wait for others' answers this time.  I've no clue on that.

Answer (score 16):

Note that
$$
\det\left(\begin{matrix}
1&ax&a^2+x^2\\1&ay&a^2+y^2\\ 1&az&a^2+z^2
\end{matrix}\right) =\det \left(\begin{matrix}
1&ax&x^2\\1&ay&y^2\\ 1&az&z^2
\end{matrix}\right)=a\cdot\det \left(\begin{matrix}
1&x&x^2\\1&y&y^2\\ 1&z&z^2
\end{matrix}\right)
$$ which boils down to Vandermonde determinant
$$
a(x-y)(y-z)(z-x).
$$

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way it's the following:
$$\Delta=\sum_{cyc}(ay(a^2+z^2)-ay(a^2+x^2))=a\sum_{cyc}(x^2z-x^2y)=a(x-y)(y-z)(z-x).$$